# C++ Lambda Function for BFS Traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Using the two functions below, how could I use a lambda function to BFS Traverse through a Graph of Thing's called x

```
i.e. Graph<Thing> x
```

which involves sending the display function to the bfsTraverse function so that the information in each Thing can be displayed.

```
void display(const Thing& c)
{
    cout<<left<<setw(3)<<c.getKey()<<" "<<left<<setw(2)<<c.getLabel()<<endl;
}

template <typename E> 
void Graph<E>::bfsTraverse(FuncType func)
{
    /* some code not necessary to describe */
}
```

So basically, I just need to understand how to use a lambda function to tie these together here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pretty straightforward. For example, let;s print values of vector using lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector <int> data{1,2,3,4};

  std::for_each (data.begin (), data.end (), [] (const int val) { std::cout << val << std::endl;});

  return 0;
}
```

last argument **[] (...)** is the lambda.
A function, which accepts lambdas, might look like this:

```
template <typename E, typename FuncType> 
void Graph<E>::bfsTraverse (FuncType func)
{
    /* some code not necessary to describe */
}
```

UPDATE

In case of a graph you should do the following. Your graph's implementation should have a method to access vertices: it might be 'getRoot', 'getSource', 'getAllNodes', it's implementation defined. I'll stick with 'getRoot'. Each vertex/node should have a method like 'getAdjacentVertices', 'getChildren', whatever. Combining all together:

```
template <typename E, typename FuncType> 
void Graph<E>::bfsTraverse (FuncType func)
{
    std::queue<Node> q;

    auto&& root = getRoot ();

    q.push (root);

    while (not q.empty ()) { 
      auto&& current = q.front ();
      q.pop ();

      func (current);

      auto&& adjacent = current.getAdjacent ();

      for (auto&& a: adjacent) {
        q.push (a);
      }
}
```

Be aware, that I deliberately omit keeping list of visited nodes and other things. But idea itself stays the same. Now you can call this function as follows:

```
Graph<E> g;
g.bfsTraverse ( [] (const Node& n) {
                  std::cout << n.to_str () << std::endl;
                } 
);
```